# "Holy Grail" three column layout using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to achieve the three-column layout generally described as the "holy grail" (see this [ALA article](http://alistapart.com/article/holygrail)) using the new `display: flex` syntax.

The requirements are as follows:

- A header and footer, with between them three columns
- The outer columns have fixed widths
- The inner column stretches to fill the space between the side columns, with a minimum and maximum width beyond which it will not stretch (so neither should the container)
- The footer should be at the bottom of the viewport, until the content actually pushes it below

I got the first three requirements down with the following code:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
  <header class="masthead">
    <h1>The Header</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="side-left column">
    Left sidebar  
  </div>
  <div class="middle column">     
    Content goes here
  </div>
  <div class="side-right column">
    Right sidebar
  </div>  
  <footer class="footer">
    &copy; Footer
  </footer>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  min-width: 500px;
  max-width: 1100px;
}
.masthead {
  flex: 1 100%;
}   
.side-left,
.side-right {
  flex: 0 0 150px;
}
.middle {
  flex: 1;
}
.footer {
  flex: 1 100%;
}
```

Live in action: [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/derivanodilo/1/)

However, I'm stuck with the 100% height. I already tried setting either some of the columns or the container to `height: 100%` or `min-height: 100%` but none seem to work. Do I need one of the many other flex properties to handle this? I can't seem to see the forest through the trees.

Comment: Did you see this: http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/holy-grail/ ?

Comment: Whoops, I did have a look at that but I guess I overlooked the obvious answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.container { min-height: 100vh; }`

Comment: `html, body { height: 100% } .container { min-height: 100% }` would also work.